# DotNetOpenAuth Claims request for OpenID does not return all values

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I would like to obtain Birth Date from DotNetOpenAuth OpenID provider.

I have set up openID server as google right now and executing code like this:

Request

```
IAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);

var fields = new ClaimsRequest();
fields.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
fields.FullName = DemandLevel.Require;
fields.BirthDate = DemandLevel.Require;
authenticationRequest.AddExtension(fields);
return authenticationRequest.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResultMvc5();
```

Response:

```
switch (response.Status) {
    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
        Session["FriendlyIdentifier"] = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
        ClaimsResponse untrustedExtension = response.GetUntrustedExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
        ClaimsRequest claimsRequest = response.GetExtension<ClaimsRequest>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        } else {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Site");
        }
}
```

Problem is that with this Claims Request I get only email address, and I would like to obtall all of specified information.

Is it possible to obtain that informations?